# The object "Script Name" is not currently available

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, actions, error, bug

I made an action, inside this action, there is a script (about set Artboard 4 Active) when I play it as a batch I get an error

> The object "Script" is not currently available.

so the script doesn't work.

Is there any solution for that?

[image]

Comment: What version of illustrator? Theres a known bug in older illustrators startting sequence that makes using scripts as part of actions impossible. One has to reload the action panel every time illustrator starts to fix it. Theres no fix other than upgrading.

Comment: Hi @joojaa thank you for your time, i have the 2020 version. But i found the solution, the problem was a command of "play action" inside the main action